# Find convolution of $\operatorname{sinc}(t-3)*\operatorname{sinc}(\pi(t+3))$

Tags: convolution

> How can I find the following [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)?$$\operatorname{sinc}(t-3)*\operatorname{sinc}(\pi(t+3))$$

Where $\operatorname{sinc}$ refers to [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html) function.

I can't understand how to use integration to compute this function.

Comment: Use the Fourier Transform, which lets you say $f(t)*g(t)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\{\mathcal{F}\{f(t)\}\cdot\mathcal{F}\{g(t)\}\}$

Comment: @AndyWalls, I understood, thank for help